# How to read data within inline frames using WGet?

Tags: wget

I am reading a web page using WGet code.

The web page has a tabular data, and instead, the below line is printed: Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.

What needs to be done to read the content within inline frames?

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have an <iframe src="X"> tag somewhere on the page you get returned. If this is the case check the src parameter of the iframe which will be an URL to the actual page that you should fetch instead of the original URL.